# vectorized implementation for pseudo pivot table in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have the following dataframe, including some vehicles and the components for said vehicles:

```
df

>>>>        Vehicle       Component
      0     Ford          Air conditioner
      1     Ford          airbag
      2     Ford          engine with 150 H/P
      3     Toyota        airbag
      4     Toyota        1-year concierge assistance
      5     Toyota        ABS breaks
      6     Chrysler      ABS breaks
      7     Chrysler      airbag
      8     Chrysler      air conditioner
      9     Chrysler      engine with 250 H/P
```

I want to create a second dataframe with the following format, i.e., a pseudo dataframe where I add a 1 to every vehicle-component existing combination, and a 0 otherwise.

```
second_df
>>>>       Vehicle      Air conditioner   airbag     engine with 150 H/P    engine with 250 H/P  ABS breaks  1-year concierge assistance  
     0     Ford         1                  1         1                      0                    0           0        
     1     Toyota       0                  1         0                      0                    1           1
     2     Chrysler     1                  1         0                      1                    1           0
```

I implemented this with thesolution posted below, but it is pretty inefficient. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`df.crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) to create a frequency table:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Component': ['Air conditioner', 'Air conditioner', 'airbag', 'engine with 150 H/P', 'airbag',
                   '1-year concierge assistance', 'ABS breaks', 'ABS breaks', 'airbag', 
                   'air conditioner', 'engine with 250 H/P'], 
     'Vehicle': ['Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Toyota', 'Toyota', 'Toyota',
                 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler']})

result = pd.crosstab(index=[df['Vehicle']], columns=[df['Component']]).clip(upper=1)
print(result)
```

yields

```
Component  1-year concierge assistance  ABS breaks  Air conditioner  \
Vehicle                                                               
Chrysler                             0           1                0   
Ford                                 0           0                1   
Toyota                               1           1                0   

Component  air conditioner  airbag  engine with 150 H/P  engine with 250 H/P  
Vehicle                                                                       
Chrysler                 1       1                    0                    1  
Ford                     0       1                    1                    0  
Toyota                   0       1                    0                    0
```

Since the frequency table may contain values greater than 1 if `df` contains duplicate rows, `clip(upper=1)` is used to reduce those values back to 1.

Comment: this is nice, but I get the following error (python 3): raise ValueError('Index contains duplicate entries, '
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Are you using `pivot`? If so, refresh the page and use the revised solution which uses `pd.crosstab`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I built, which is pretty inefficient because it uses a nested loop. Would appreciate if anyone posts a more elegant implementation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

data['vehicle'] = data['vehicle'].apply(str)

vhs = np.unique(data['vehicle'])
vhs = [x for x in vhs if str(x) != 'nan']


data['Component'] = data['Component'].apply(str)
components = np.unique(data['Component'])
components = [x for x in components if str(x) != 'nan']

componentes = ['vehicle'] + components

my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=componentes)

vhs = np.array(vhs)

my_df['vehicles'] = vhs

my_df = my_df.fillna(0)

for vh in vhs:
    sub_data = data[data['vehicle']==vh]
    compies = np.unique(sub_data['Component'])
    for comp in compies:
        my_df[comp][my_df['vehicles']==vh] = 1

my_df.to_csv('my_vhs.csv',index=False)
```